# Process.GetProcessesByName in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I'm having an issue related the the BackgroundWorker object and don't have enough experience in C# to understand what's going on. The program is an off-site patching utility. It works but I the UI isn't updating correctly because the processing and UI loop are in the same thread, so I'm looking at moving the processing into a BackgroundWorker.

Since executables are being patched, the patching process checks to make sure they aren't running before files are copied. The problem I'm seeing is with Process.GetProcessesByName. If I run Process.GetProcessesByName in *bg_InstallPatch* it appears to work fine, if I call it from within the *handleLocalRunningProcesses* method the "Couldn't get process information from performance counter." exception is thrown, and I can't find any documentation on why that is. Does something similar to running *Invoke* on a Form need to happen when calling the method?

The highest .NET runtime level I have available is 3.5.

```
        private void handleLocalRunningProcesses(bool killIfFound = true)
    {
        logger.Debug("Looking up local processes");
        String[] filesToUpload = files.Split(',');
        foreach (String file in filesToUpload)
        {
            String[] fileName = file.Split('.');
            logger.Debug("Checking " + fileName[0]);
        /********  V  Exception Throw Here  V  ********/
            foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName(fileName[0])) 
                try
                {
                    int pid = proc.Id;
                    logger.Info("Process " + pid + " found running for " + file);
                    if (killIfFound)
                        try
                        {
                            logger.Info("Attempting to kill process " + pid);
                            proc.Kill();
                            if (!proc.WaitForExit(TIMEOUT_KILL_IN_MILLIS))
                                throw new ApplicationException(String.Format(ERROR_PROCESS_RUNNING, pid, "localhost"));
                            else
                                logger.Info("Process has been terminated.");
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            logger.Error(e.Message, e);
                            throw new ApplicationException(String.Format(ERROR_PROCESS_RUNNING, pid, "localhost"));
                        }
                }
                finally
                {
                    proc.Dispose();
                }
        }
        logger.Debug("Finished looking up local processes");
    }

    public void bg_InstallPatch(Object sender, DoWorkEventArgs ea)
    {
        try
        {
            //..... Other Code .....
            if (updateLocal)
            {
                logger.Info("Starting Local Updates");
                /***Testing***/
                logger.Debug("2Looking up local processes");
                String[] filesToUpload = files.Split(',');
                foreach (String file in filesToUpload)
                {
                    String[] fileName = file.Split('.');
                    logger.Debug("2Checking " + fileName[0]);
        /****** This works fine ******/
                    foreach (Process proc in Process.GetProcessesByName(fileName[0]))
                        try
                        {
                            int pid = proc.Id;
                            logger.Info("2Process " + pid + " found running for " + file);
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            proc.Dispose();
                        }
                }
                /******/
                handleLocalRunningProcesses(true);
                //..... More Code .....
             }
             //..... More Code .....
        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            logger.Error("Error installing patch", e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    public void installPatch()
    {
        //..... Unrelated Code ....
            logger.Info("Starting patch installation");
            BackgroundWorker patcher = new BackgroundWorker();
            patcher.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(bg_InstallPatch);
            patcher.RunWorkerCompleted += new RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler(bg_ProgressClose);
            patcher.RunWorkerAsync(bar);
        //..... More Code .....
    }
```

Comment: Is the string files a global variable?

Comment: This is run from in a class, so _files_ is scoped to the class. But the answer is yes. Assume any variables not defined locally are part of the class. I can update the code to show them if it helps.

Comment: Won't the simplest and most efficient solution to be to pass the Processes List as a parameter to handleLocalRunningProcesses? In fact, aren't doing duplicative work?

Comment: Be sure to google the exception message first, you have not eliminated the obvious reasons you are getting this exception.  Which have nothing to do with the BackgroundWorker, it just lets you get this to fail quicker.  Most obvious failure mode is that you are leaking handles because you are not calling the Process.Dispose() method and the garbage collector is not running often enough to keep you out of trouble.

Comment: I don't see any exception here.  I think you're trying to pull one over on us.

Comment: @SILENT Yes that does work, but I'm interested in understanding why it doesn't work as coded.

Comment: @HansPassant I updated the question with the changes I made for the Dispose method, but it's still throwing the exception. Let me know if I misunderstood. I've been through everything that Google could throw at me and wasn't able to find why this is happening. Just to be clear, this works fine if there isn't a BackgroundWorker. It also works fine if Process.GetProcessesByName is called directly in bg_InstallPatch, it's only when the BackgroundWorker calls another method and that's what calls Process.GetProcessesByName that I start seeing an exception. I figured it was some obscure C#-ism.

Comment: @Will Really... hmm, are you running it in Visual Studio or as an executable? My understanding is that the debugger will prevent BackgroundWorker exceptions from being handled correctly.

Comment: @Will Thank you, it working for you made me realize what the cause probably is. This program has to run on XP, when I ran it on Windows 10 it's no longer showing this behavior. How do I close out the question? Answer it myself and accept that answer?

Comment: Yes, you can add details about the solution in an answer, then accept it after the waiting period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the why, but I found the cause. The program showing this behavior is required to run on Windows XP under .NET 3.5. The issue no longer presented itself when running on Windows 10 with .NET 4.5.1 installed. A second test on Windows 8.0  with .NET 3.5 installed also worked. Verified that the program continues to fail in a second, unrelated XP environment with .NET 3.5 installed. The same executable was used for all tests.

Even though the program is compiled as a 32-bit executable, it should still be pointed out that XP is 32-bit and both Windows 8 and 10 were 64-bit. Just in case this behavior would present itself in the 32-bit version of newer operating systems, though I doubt it would.

Comment: .NET 4.5 [changed the behavior of unobserved exceptions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/09/28/task-exception-handling-in-net-4-5.aspx)